# How to access a vector of pointers to a vector of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector, reference

I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind accessing a vector which stores pointers.

. I have 3 classes, a student class which has studentName, studentNumber, and a vector of pointers to the student's courses. vector courses.

. My Courses class has a courseName, courseID and vector students which models a list of all the students in that course

. The registration class has a vector list of both students and courses: vector studentList; 
vector courseList;

My ultimate goal is to read in a text file in the registration class and store all students in the studentList, each student will then have a vector of pointers to their courses. Each course is also stored in the courseList which points to the respective students.

Now I'm not sure if this even sounds correct though I'll provide a code snip-it of what im having problems with:

in student.h:

```
inline void Student::SetCourse(Unit &myCourse) 
{ 

courses.push_back(&myCourse); 

}
```

// This should set the pointer of the associated course ...I think

So my theory is if I wanted to display the associated courses with a specific student, all I have to do is call that student object from the studentList and then display the units which are referenced in the vector of unit pointers.

So if this looks right. If I was in the registration class, how would I access the pointers to the courseList, if this is even logically correct or possible?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: You've tagged with everything except the language (which is the only meaningful tag).

Comment: Taking a pointer from such a reference looks *wrong*. Not in a way that it won't work, but but in a way that makes my "this will get invalidated" sense tickling.

Comment: you need a const std::vector<Courses*>& Student::GetCourses() const function, which returns the courses member you just assembled in SetCourses. Then it's just a iteration through the returned vector from GetCourses.

Comment: you already have a courselist object in registration class. Why can't you use that ?